# Moving around the vim command line

Tags: vim

I've been a vim user for a while now and I know how to move around the files, but is there anyway to do so on the editor command line itself (is there a name for that?).

e.g. I typed `:vimgerp /sometext/ files/*.js` and I realized I spelled `:vimgrep` incorrectly and I want to just jump to the beginning of that line and fix it. Any other sort of small tips here (jump between words -- neither w,e nor alt+left/right seem to work) also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_20.html

```
<Left>          one character left
<Right>         one character right
<S-Left> or <C-Left>    one word left
<S-Right> or <C-Right>  one word right
CTRL-B or <Home>    to begin of command line
CTRL-E or <End>     to end of command line
```

Comment: Is <S-Left> and <C-Left> Shift/Ctrl? Tried it and it didn't work offhand, though I'm guessing it could be to my terminal (iTerm2) settings.

Comment: Yes, *Shift* and *Control*. Very much depends on terminal.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method would be to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>. This opens your command in the command-line window where you can edit your misspelled command like any other plain text.

#### from vimhelp

> OPEN                      *c_CTRL-F* *q:* *q/* *q?*
>
> There are two ways to open the command-line window:
>
> 1. From Command-line mode, use the key specified with the 'cedit' option.    The default is CTRL-F when 'compatible' is not set.
> 2. From Normal mode, use the "q:", "q/" or "q?" command.    This starts editing an Ex command-line ("q:") or search string ("q/" or
>    "q?").  Note that this is not possible while recording is in progress
>    (the    "q" stops recording then).

Answer (score 0):

It's not the fastest and therefore probably only worth it for long commands, but you could just hit enter on the incorrect command as is, `u`ndo any incorrect changes if necessary, then  open up your command history with `q:`, where you can edit it as you like. Enter then runs the command if you have your cursor over it in the command history buffer.

Also, shift+arrow left/right jumps between words in command mode, and you can use home/end to go to the beginning and end.